# JSON object parsing using retrofit2.0

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson, retrofit2

I'm trying to parse a JSON object using retrofit 2.0 following [this](http://www.pratikbutani.com/2016/05/android-tutorial-json-parsing-using-retrofit-part-1/) guide, but it doesn't work. I think it's because of a difference in JSON format.

Here is a nested JSON object with the format:

```
{
    "SearchService": {
        "list_total_count": 531,
        "RESULT": {
            "CODE": "INFO-001",
            "MESSAGE": "SUCCESS"
        },
        "row": [{
            "ID": "1983",
            "NAME": "SAN",
            "NUM": "38",
        }, {
            "ID": "1984",
            "NAME": "DU",
            "NUM": "27",
        }]
    }
}
```

Here is class code using SerializedName:

RowList.java

```
public class RowList {
    @SerializedName("row")
    @Expose
    private ArrayList<Row> rows= new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<Row> getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    public void setRows(ArrayList<Row> rows) {
        this.rows= rows;
    }
}
```

Row.java

```
public class Row{

    @SerializedName("ID")
    @Expose
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("NAME")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("NUM")
    @Expose
    private String num;

    /*getter setter*/

}
```

Comment: Retrofit doesn't parse the JSON. Gson does. You can use this site to get a good start. http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Note: `"NUM":"38",` <-- That comma makes this invalid JSON

Comment: Im using com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2 library

Comment: Right. So, you should be reading over the Gson documentation for how to convert your JSON into Java objects. Retrofit is only used to communicate over the network. https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read that guide.

> There are two approaches to create Model class. The first way is the manual approach, which requires you to learn how to use the [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md) library. The second approach is you can also auto-generate the Java classes you need by capturing the JSON output and using [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Looks like you've attempted approach one, but haven't (yet?) tried reading over the Gson documentation.

---

Okay, you have a `Row`. That covers the objects within `"row": [...]`, so you also need objects for the following:

- `"SearchService": {}`
- `"RESULT": {}`

I don't think the `RowList` class is necessary. `List<Row>` is fine.

For example,

```
class Result {
    @SerializedName("CODE")
    String code;
    @SerializedName("MESSAGE")
    String message;
}

class SearchService {
    @SerializedName("list_total_count")
    long count;
    @SerializedName("RESULT")
    Result result;
    @SerializedName("row")
    private ArrayList<Row> rows= new ArrayList<>();
}
```

(removed `@Expose` for conciseness)

Then, Retrofit would use `Call<SearchService>`